# How do it set username to security context

Tags: spring-boot, authentication, spring-security

I am using Spring boot.

I am using my own authentication server to authenticate my users.

So after calling my auth server, with my result which is a json of `UserInfo` class.

How am I able to set it in security context?

I see my class as a different class type of user from `org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User` and `org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails`.

This is my `JwtAuthenticationFilter` class.

```
@Component
public class JwtAuthenticationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationService authenticationService;

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {

        getJwtFromRequest(request, response, filterChain);
    }

    private void getJwtFromRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String bearerToken = request.getHeader("Authorization");

        if (!StringUtils.hasText(bearerToken) || !bearerToken.startsWith("Bearer ")) {

            throw new AccessTokenMissingException("No access token found in request headers");
        }

        // Call auth server to validate token
        try {
            ResponseEntity<String> result = authenticationService.getUserInfo(bearerToken.substring(7));

            UserInfo user = new ObjectMapper().readValue(result.getBody(), UserInfo.class);
            System.out.println(user.toString());

            // Invalid access token
            if (!result.getStatusCode().is2xxSuccessful()) {
                throw new InvalidAccessTokenException("Invalid access token");
            }


        } catch (HttpClientErrorException.Unauthorized | IOException e) {
            throw new InvalidAccessTokenException("Invalid access token");
        }

        //add to security context

        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

This is my `UserInfo` class.

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class UserInfo implements Serializable {
    private List<String> role = new ArrayList<>();
    private String username
    private String email;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Spring [Security Reference documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#setting-the-securitycontextholder-contents-directly)

> All you need to do is write a filter (or equivalent) that reads the
>   third-party user information from a location, **build a Spring
>   Security-specific Authentication object, and put it into the
>   SecurityContextHolder**. In this case you also need to think about
>   things which are normally taken care of automatically by the built-in
>   authentication infrastructure. For example, you might need to
>   pre-emptively create an HTTP session to cache the context between
>   requests, before you write the response to the client

An example for creating a simple Authentication object is also provided

https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#what-is-authentication-in-spring-security

```
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(anAuthentication);
```

Here **anAuthentication** is an Authentication object to be set to the SecurityContext.

Update :

[Authentication](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.12.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/Authentication.html)

Comment: it doesnt make sense, my username and pwd is from another auth server. so it is not right to supply username and pwd.

Comment: You need to provide an Authentication object